# iOS UIView setFrame animation error

Tags: ios, uiview

I am having a weird error while animating a couple of view in iOS. My goal is to switch from a custom "Split View". You can see what's going on in this youtube video: http://youtu.be/ZWbf2bQYMns

You can see the weird "bump" in the Y value of the UIImageView, and I have been wondering how to fix it for quite a while now.

This is the View Controller's interface:

```
@interface VideoSharing_Pad : UIViewController
{   
    IBOutlet UIView *videoCallView;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;  //This is "inside" mediaView
    IBOutlet UIView *mediaView;
    CGRect mediaRect;
    CGRect videoCallRect;
    CGRect imageRect;
}
```

In viewDidLoad I store both views doing:

```
//Get frames from XIB
mediaRect = mediaView.frame;
videoCallRect = videoCallView.frame;
imageRect = imageView.frame;
```

And this is the code that executes when I want to switch from the Split View to a full Screen Mode:

```
- (IBAction)toggleFullScreen:(id)sender 
{
    if (iScreenMode == callAndShareMedia) {
        CGRect fullScreenRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
        CGRect dissapearRect = CGRectMake(0, - videoCallView.bounds.size.height, videoCallView.bounds.size.width, videoCallView.bounds.size.height);

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                              delay:0.1
                            options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{

                             [videoCallView setFrame:dissapearRect];
                             [imageView setFrame:fullScreenRect];
                             [mediaView setFrame:fullScreenRect];
                         } 
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){

                         }];

        iScreenMode = onlyShareMedia;
        return;
    } 
    else if (iScreenMode == onlyShareMedia)
    {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                              delay:0.1
                            options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{

                             [videoCallView setFrame:videoCallRect];
                             [mediaView setFrame:mediaRect];
                             [imageView setFrame:imageRect];  

                         } 
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){    
                         }];
        iScreenMode = callAndShareMedia;
        return;
    }     
}
```

I would really appreciate any help I can get. Thanks a lot!

this is a screenshot of the XIB:

[image]

as you can see from the screenshot and the .h file, the imageView is inside an UIView called mediaView, The other UIView, videoCallView is the one with the three dummy pictures.

Comment: I do not quite understand the relation of `videoCallView` and `mediaView` and `imageView`. It would help to have a screen shot + some overlay annotation that explains which area corresponds to which view object.

Comment: @barley this is a screenshot of the XIB: http://i.imgur.com/xl0PU.png as you can see from the screenshot and the .h file, the imageView is inside an UIView called mediaView, The other UIView, videoCallView is the one with the three dummy pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question indeed. It definitely has to do with animating superview and subview at the same time. I did sample program, and reproduced similar situation.

My workaround would be to avoid animating the superview (`mediaView`), and expand only the subview (`imageView`) to full rectangle. Since your superview (`mediaView`) does not have much, it should not give so different user experience.

So, instead of

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:0.1
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     [videoCallView setFrame:dissapearRect];
                     [imageView setFrame:fullScreenRect];
                     [mediaView setFrame:fullScreenRect];
 }];
```

You can do

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:0.1
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     [videoCallView setFrame:dissapearRect];
                     [imageView setFrame:(CGRect){fullScreenRect.origin.x - mediaRect.origin.x, fullScreenRect.origin.y - mediaRect.origin.y, fullScreenRect.size}];
 }];
```

For coming back to normal mode, you can just ignore `mediaView` animation. Probably you want to move (animate) the toggleButton along with other animation as well.

@jrturton's answer (second part) seemed a nice workaround, but it did not work on my sample code. It worked on the way to go (expansion), but bumped on the way back (shrink), for the reason I don't know why. But don't dismiss his answer because of my comment, it could be me.

Comment: @barley Thanks a lot for the effort you put on figuring out what could be making this happening. I tried out your code and this is the result: (never-mind the button, i didn't add animations to it) http://youtu.be/y-wk-8yLW3M . 

As you can see, when the picture is 4:3 there is no noticeable difference for the end user, however when the picture is 16:9 the solution is not so elegant. BTW, the problem in the original code is in the going back transition, since the first one is OK. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: @PierluigiCifani Don't worry. Thanks to the storyboard, it just took 5 min to reproduce the problem itself. (Trying different work arounds that did not work, was another matter... :)) So, I assume you are talking about the boundary of the gray area (from `mediaView`) and the black area (from `videoCallView`). My workaround woud be this: add a gray empty view as the subview of `mediaView` and animate that instead of `mediaView` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. I can't view your video from work but I expect your issue is that you are resizing both a view and its subview during an animation, there will probably be interference from any autoresizing masks (do you have them?) - the superview will change the size of the subview, then the interpolated frame will be applied.

If you think about it there will also be a stage where your image view has to animate more quickly than the superview as it has more ground to cover to get to the same final rect. The interpolation worked out by the animation may struggle with this.

If removing any autoresizing masks doesn't work, you might need to split the animation into two - one to increase the size of the superview, and another to then zoom the image view to full size.

Comment: no, I don't have any autoresizing masks established. I didn't thought it was necessary since I want to control both the mediaView and the imageView frame myself.

Comment: OK, the second part of my answer still stands though.